# How do I find out whether a monad is commutative?

Tags: haskell, monads, commutativity

The documentation for [Control.Monad.List.ListT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-List.html) states that it "does not yield a monad unless the argument monad is commutative."

1. How do I find out whether a monad is commutative? Is there a CommutativeMonad typeclass? Should there be?
2. In particular, is [Control.Monad.RWS.Lazy.RWS](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-RWS-Lazy.html) a commutative monad?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, a monad is commutative if the expression `a >>= \x -> b >>= \y -> f x y` is equivalent to `b >>= \y -> a >>= \x -> f x y`.

In other words, it is commutative if the order of side effects is not important. We can replace the expression:

```
do a <- ma
   b <- mb
   f a b
```

with one which switches the arguments.

```
do b <- mb
   a <- ma
   f a b
```

<strike>Most</strike> Many common monads are commutative, but you can determine if a particular monad is commutative by either looking at the design and logicking it, or by writing a small program to test it with appropriate expressions (which naturally depend on the nature of the monad). As far as I know there is no CommutativeMonad typeclass.

Comment: I would say the opposite, most monads are not commutative, can you name any examples besides `Maybe` and `Reader`?

Comment: I use MonadSupply and Random pretty often, and of course there are the implementations of certain unordered data structures like multisets. But that's a fair criticism.

Comment: MonadSupply does not appear to be commutative by your definition. `runSupply (do {a <- supply; b <- supply; return (a - b)}) [1,2]` → `-1` but `runSupply (do {b <- supply; a <- supply; return (a - b)}) [1,2]` → `1`. Is there a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: @Tarrasch: [This talk from ICFP 2009](http://vimeo.com/6590617) has some cool examples of commutative monads.

Comment: I've seen that before. It's a great lecture.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no CommutativeMonad class.  And RWS is not commutative.  For a monad to be commutative you have to be able to reorder the effects without anything changing.